# Excel: convert Entered value to URL path

Tags: excel, vba

I am using google doc and want to allow users to to direct enter value into cell (e.g. column A). entered value will be turned into a URL path parameter. The URL always starts with the same URL segment.

Explanation:

enter "CW-7". the value of the cell will turn into www.website.com/CW-7
enter "BH-67". the value of the cell will turn into www.website.com/BH-67

How can this be done?
Any script sample to automate this?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind having two columns you could just have the next column use the `Hyperlink` function.

Assuming you are entering your "CW-7" values into Column A, then in Column B you could have:

```
=HYPERLINK("www.website.com/"&A1,A1)
```

The `&` is the same as the Concatenate function which basically just smashes any text strings together. This way you can create hyperlinks that change with the data in your cells.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you combine them.  Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do with it once you have included the cell value with the website name, not much else I can show you.

```
Dim strURL As String
Dim ws as Excel.Application

Set ws = Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

strURL = "www.website.com/" & ws.Range("A1").Value

msgbox (strURL)
```

Comment: If OP wants to insert a hyperlink, just wrap `Hyperlink()` around `strURL`, i.e. `Cells(1,1).Formula = "=Hyperlink(strURL,""Link"")`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could have it replace your entered text directly with the URL, automatically after you enter it. This code is rough (I just wrote it) so you might need to tweak it, but it illustrates the idea:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Columns("A:A")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://www.google.com/#q=" & Cells(LastRow, 1).Text

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(LastRow, 1), Address:=URL, TextToDisplay:=Cells(LastRow, 1).Text

    Application.EnableEvents = True

Else
End If
End Sub
```

Also I think it is "rough" because it isn't smart: it just turns the LAST cell you entered into Column A into a URL. If you start deleting cells from Column A it will start to convert previously converted cells and you'll get a mess.

Edit: This code only works when pasted in the module for the sheet you want it to run on. Sheet1(Main) or Sheet2(Sheet2) etc.

Edit2: Upon further testing I realize it does NOT make a mess, because it still uses the TEXT from the previous URL "friendly name" to rebuild the new URL, meaning you can safely delete rows and it won't destroy any remaining URLs. :)